# run/load VS2022 solution / projects with VS2019 gives error about MSBuild versions

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to open a VS2022 solution on VS2019 but I'm getting this error message

`the project file cannot be opened, veresino 7.0.313 of the .net sdk requires at least version 17.4.0 of msbuilds, the current available of msbuild is 16.00.2.50704. change the .net sdk specified in global.json`

I see no global.json file anywhere, I tried to add the Directory.Build.props with no luck and modify project file with line

```
<MSBuildToolsVersion>16.0</MSBuildToolsVersion>
```

But then get the error about the MSBuildToolsVersion propery being reserved and cannot be modified.

Wondering if there's an update to make it run. What seems odd is that I can run the projects from VS Code and is shownig the MSBuild17 message when doing `dotnet build`